# Trying to find any home directory that is writable by anyone

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, bash-scripting

I am trying to locate any user home directories and their files that are writable by anyone.

I wrote this:

```
find /home -type d -perm -200 | grep . || 
   echo no world-writable directories here
```

This is only detecting directories, but I would like to also add files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getent passwd | 
cut -d: -f1,6 | 
while IFS=: read user home; do 
    if [[ -d $home ]] && (( (0$(stat -c %a $home) & 2) == 2 )); then 
        echo $user $home
    fi
done
```

The test for world-writable can also be written like this:

```
[[ $(stat -c %A $home) == *?w? ]]
```

Explained:

1. `getent passwd` - get information about all users on the system in an /etc/passwd format
2. `cut ...` - select only userid and home directory
3. `[[ -d $home ]]` - ensure home-dir is a directory
4. `(( (0$(stat -c %a $home) & 2) == 2 ))`:
   `stat -c %a $home` returns the file permissions in octal form (ex: `755`). Prefix a zero so that bash knows it's an octal number. Then perform a bitwise-and to get the "world-writable" bit. If that value is zero, then the directory is not world writable. If the value is 2 (binary 10), then the directory is world writable.
5. So, if it is a directory, and it is world-writable, then output the userid and directory.
6. the alternate form `[[ $(stat -c %A $home) == *?w? ]]` looks at the file permissions in string form (ex: `drwxr-xr-x`) and then checks to see if the 2nd last character is a "w"

Comment: I don't understand some lines, what is happening at if:

Comment: @user230654, explanation added

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you want to find all files and directories under `/home` that have permissions of `200`, you can do

```
find /home -perm -200
```

That, however, is not the list of world writeable files and folders, `200` means the file is writeable by its owner. If you want all files and folders that can be written by everyone do this instead:

```
find /home -perm -a=w
```

Your `grep .` does nothing. `.` means "Match ANY character" so it will always be true. If you are looking for files or folders whose name begins with `.`, you can do need `grep "^\."`.

Comment: find . -perm -002 this is my final :) thanx